# Getting color array to put it in the function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, intersection-observer

I am working on javascript IntersectionObserver property.

I want get colors from `colors` array to put here `entry.target.style.backgroundColor= col;  //changing to background color to the color from colors array` in the `action` function.
But only ones I get is `blue` which is the last one of `colors` array.

How can I get each color from array and put them to function?
Also, is it possible to get the color back to the original background color when scrolling up back?

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const colors = ['green','brown', 'blue'];

for(let i=0; i < colors.length; i ++) {
  col = colors[i];
}

const action = function (entries) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if(entry.isIntersecting) {
      entry.target.style.backgroundColor= col;  //changing to background color to the color from colors array
    } else {
      return false;   // going back to original background color???
    }
  });
}

const options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: "30% 0px",
  threshold: 1
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(action, options);

sections.forEach(section => {
  observer.observe(section);
});
```

```css
header { height: 100vh; background: #ccc;}
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: .5s;
}
.block1 {background: #666;}
.block2 { background: #aaa;}
.block3 { background: #333;}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<section class="block block1">green</section>
<section class="block block2">brown</section>
<section class="block block3">blue</section>
```

Comment: Which color from the array do you want to use? Right now your for loop assigns the last item in the `colors` array to `col`

Comment: @Maaz Syed Adeeb
Thanks for your comment.
I want each every colors.
green for block1, brown for block2, blue for block3.
I don't know how to get each color to use in the function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit:

According to the [IntersectionObserver api](https://www.w3.org/TR/intersection-observer/) we can't call takeRecords because it would be empty in the callback (since queue is flushed) (with wish to get all the observed records)

And [intersectionobserverentry](https://www.w3.org/TR/intersection-observer/#intersectionobserverentry) does not gives back a reference to the observed nodes either

So we may fallback to retrieve the sections to get the current entry index from

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const colors = ['green','brown', 'blue'];

const action = function (entries) {
  entries.forEach(entry => { 
    if(entry.isIntersecting) {
      // retrieve the entry's index from sections
      const i = [...sections].indexOf(entry.target)
      
      // or... traverse to its parent praying for all the observed entries to be there
      // console.log(entry.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('section'))
      entry.target.style.backgroundColor= colors[i];  //changing to background color to the color from colors array
    } else {
      return false;   // going back to original background color???
    }
  });
}

const options = {
  root: null,
  rootMargin: "30% 0px",
  threshold: 1
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(action, options);

sections.forEach(section => {
  observer.observe(section);
});
```

```css
header { height: 100vh; background: #ccc;}
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  transition: .5s;
}
.block1 {background: #666;}
.block2 { background: #aaa;}
.block3 { background: #333;}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<section class="block block1">green</section>
<section class="block block2">brown</section>
<section class="block block3">blue</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I can get only green color in this way. It's weird because showing different way between when opning the page from top to scroll down which only green color to show up and reload it in the middle of the page which shows up all three colors.
Probably `IntersectionObserver` and loop are not a good match?
Maybe I need to find out different way. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I have updated code above @user10991526 I think you do want to use the observer. A better alternative may be to encode some data-colorIndex to your observed section (then you would read the colorIndex from the current target). Approach I propose implies to know which sections have been listened which is quite intrusive...

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I wanted. And yes, I wanted to use observer for my practice...
I only cared about colors array but I needed to get sections index to be paired with.
Now I understand what you mean. Thank you for your kind help!!!

Answer (score 1):

One way you can accomplish it is by using CSS classes. So, when the element is intersecting, add an `intersecting` class and when it's not, remove it. And have the corresponding CSS for the matching block. I'm not so sure about the IntersectionObserver options, but I've changed them to give you an idea on how this approach works.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

const action = function(entries) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    const elem = entry.target;
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      if (!elem.classList.contains("intersect")) {
        elem.classList.add("intersect");
      }
    } else {
      elem.classList.remove("intersect");
    }
  });
}

const options = {
//  root: null,
//    rootMargin: "30% 0px",
  threshold: 0.5
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(action, options);

sections.forEach(section => {
  observer.observe(section);
});
```

```css
header {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: .5s;
}

.block1 {
  background: #666;
}

.block1.intersect {
  background: green;
}

.block2 {
  background: #aaa;
}

.block2.intersect {
  background: brown;
}

.block3 {
  background: #333;
}

.block3.intersect {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<section class="block block1">green</section>
<section class="block block2">brown</section>
<section class="block block3">blue</section>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I actually already tried your way. I just want to try to it in another way to improve javascript using array in this case. Thank you very much for your help anyways!!